# Tracing not working in Asp.net MVC 5 site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, trace, tracelistener

I have a custom trace listener (inherits TraceListener) setup that logs the trace information to a database.

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="MyApplication" switchValue="Information" />
    </sources>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add name="sqlLogListener" type="MyApplication.SqlDatabaseTraceListener, MyApplication" initializeData="connectionStringName:=errorTrace" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

This works fine on my dev machine, but on the production machine, I'm unable to get any of the trace messages to show up on the database.  My guess is that this might be a iis configuration issue.  I've tested the connection to the errorTrace database, and I can successfully query and show information.

I've looked around anywhere and cannot find any relevant information for this behavior.  Also, my production machine is using iis 7.5.

**UPDATE**: I'm using windows authentication. My production machine and dev machine are both hooked to to the same domain.  Also, my dev machine is iis8.5 and production machine is iis7.5, but this should not be the issue.

Comment: This references a connectionStringName-- I can't see your connection string section. Also, since you have a custom listener, I can only guess what environment specific dependencies it might have. One possibility is you are using windows authentication locally and may or may not have all the pieces in place to use windows auth. There is no particular reason why System.Diagnostic trace wouldn't work in IIS as compare to a console app or casinni, the two technologies are unaware of each other (i.e. no dependencies)

Comment: @MatthewMartin I updated my question with more information. I agree, I don't see any particular reason that would cause this issue.

Comment: Double hop. http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue You can eliminate it as a possibility by temporarily trying a sql auth connection string.

Comment: Could be a security setting or a variety of other things. I would configure dev to match prod before I tried anything else.

Comment: @AdmiralAdama I tried that. I did a deployment where dev and prod both configs and code match. I still get this error with that configuration. And with that configuration, tracing in dev still works fine.

Comment: @Pathachiever11 but the IIS version is different? I was proposing matching server configuration. Make sure you are running with the same security context and level etc

Comment: @AdmiralAdama oh...that is one thing I can't match. =( My server is 2008R2. I don't think that's the issue though, because i have a number of applications running on .net 3.5 and iis7.5, which reuse the sql tracing component, and are able to trace just fine.

Comment: No exceptions or anything?

Comment: @AdmiralAdama Nope. It's one of the weirdest issues I've hit.

Comment: Burn the server down.... But actually I would trace by hand by writing some state things to a text file or email to yourself or a database.